# Windows firewall setting

Tags: windows

I am trying to allow internet access only to a specific IP by adding new rules to the Windows Defender Firewall's "outbound rules." Here is what I have attempted:

```
1. Blocked all outbound internet connections.
2. Allowed all programs and ports for a specific IP.
```

However, it did not work as intended. So, I tried a different approach:

```
1. Blocked all TCP connections.
2. Allowed all programs and ports for a specific IP.
```

Yet, the connection to that IP still did not go through. Specifically, when I tried to establish an HTTP connection in the browser, I received a message indicating that the internet was blocked. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows security, block rules generally take precedence over allow rules. What you want is to block all *by default* and then create a specific allow rule. If you create an actual "block all outbound connections" or "block all TCP connections" rule, those will prevent all traffic regardless of other rules; you must instead change the *default* policy.

- Go to "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security", which will open MMC (Microsoft Management Console).
- With "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" selected in the left pane, click the "Properties" action in the right pane (or click "Windows Defender Firewall properties" in the middle).
- Select the firewall profile you want to configure (usually either "Public" or "Private") using the tabs at the top of the window that opens.
- In the "State" portion of the window, select the drop-down next to "Outbound connections:" and change it to "Block". Repeat for any other profiles you want this to apply to.

Once this is done, all outbound traffic that doesn't match an Allow rule will fail. However, you can add rules to solve this. If you want to allow all traffic on all ports and protocols and from all apps so long as it goes to a specific IP address, do the following:

- Click on Outbound Rules in the left pane.
- Select "New Rule..." from the Actions pane on the right, or the context menu.
- Select "Custom" as the other options don't allow filtering on destination host, and click Next at the bottom.
- Select "All programs" and click Next.
- Leave "Protocol type:" at "Any" unless you want to allow only specific protocols, and click Next.
- Under "**Which remote IP addresses does this rule apply to?**", select "These IP addresses:" and then click Add and specify the address you want to allow.

  - Be sure to leave the *local* IP addresses option set to "Any IP address" unless you specifically want this to only apply to one of multiple local network adapters and you know the address of that adapter and know that the address won't change!
  - Click Next.
- Choose "Allow the connection". Don't use "Allow the connection if it is secure" unless you have configured IPSec. Click Next.
- De-select any profiles you don't want the rule to apply to. Note that, being an "Allow" rule, it'll only be relevant on profiles where outbound traffic isn't allowed by default. Click Next.
- Give the rule a recognizable name, such as "Allow traffic to <HOST or IP>" and then click Finish.

**Make sure you've removed or disabled any "Block all outbound traffic"-type rules!**

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have already tried as you say, but it does not work.